# Android how i can display the text file from sd card and display the text one by one

Tags: android, textview, android-sdcard

I have a text file on my sd card which contains the following data:

```
Farhan shah
Noman Shah
Ahmad shah
Mohsin shah
Haris shah
```

I have one `TextView` into my app,now I want when I run my app,my `TextView` display just the 1st name "Farhan Shah", and after x seconds it's display "Noman Shah" and so on..
but now when I run my app it reads all the text and display in my textview.
any help will be highly appreciated,Thanks.

This is my code:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    //Get the text file
    File file = new File(sdcard,"test.txt");

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            text.append(line);
            text.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    t = new TextView(this);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_textlist);
    t.setText(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you read in the whole file into text before you set your textview to it's content.

try it like this:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"test.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_textlist);
Timer mTimer = new Timer();

TimerTask Next = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
                    String line = br.readLine();
                    if(line!= null)
                        t.setText(line);
                    else
                        mTimer.cancel();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }   
    }
};

mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(Next,100L,TimeXinMillis);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  text.append('\n'); add some delimiter like  text.append('|'); 
later split it into a string array and loop through

```
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_textlist);
text.append('|');
String[] splitText = text.toString().split("|");
for(int i = 0; i < splitText.length; i++) {
 t.setText(splitText[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
  String line;

  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

   textnames.add(line);
      text.append(line);
      text.append('\n');
  }
       }
catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how is this an answer? where did `textnames` come from?